# Dependency Injection with XAML, is it possible?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a class which takes advantage of the new Xamarin Forms Shell Search, to populate the Items source of the search bar I would like to use my repositories to get a list of items.

Using the Prism MVVM framework I would rather use DI than creating a new instance myself. Doing this however, my code does not compile as the Search handler  referenced in the XAML code complains about not having a parameterless constructor. Is there a work around this? Or is there a better way? Please do let me know

#### Search handler class (How I want it to be)

```
public class IngredientsSearchHandler : SearchHandler
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public IngredientsSearchHandler(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
            {
                ItemsSource = null;
            }
            else
            {
                ItemsSource = _unitOfWork.IngredientRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(newValue.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

#### View which references search handler

The error is : "**There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'unitOfWork' of 'IngredientsSearchHandler.IngredientsSearchHandler(IUnitOfWork)'**"

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestApp.Controls"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.IngredientsView">

    <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <controls:IngredientsSearchHandler Placeholder="Enter ingredient.."
                                           ShowsResults="true"
                                           DisplayMemberName="Name"
                                           Keyboard="Text">
            <controls:IngredientsSearchHandler.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:IngredientsSearchHandler.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:IngredientsSearchHandler>
    </Shell.SearchHandler>

    <ContentPage.Content>
            <Label Text="Test"/>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is remove `IngredientsSearchHandler` altogether and bind `Query` and `ItemsSource` of a regular `SearchHandler` to properties on the view model and react to changes to the query *there* (by updating the `ItemsSource`).

The view model gets its dependencies injected automatically (because you use the `ViewModelLocator`), and I'm not aware of any way to intercept the creation of controls defined in xaml to use the container.

Comment: excellent suggestion! worked like a charm and I have everything encapsulated within my ViewModel now!!! I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is yes you can use DependencyInjection in XAML with the ContainerProvider.

```
<ContentPage xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             xmlns:converters="using:MyProject.Converters">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <prism:ContainerProvider x:TypeArguments="converters:SomeConverter" x:Key="someConverter" />
  </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense! What I don't understand is how that removes the error? I replicated what you have done but the error still persists underlining my reference to the search handler. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: You need to pass this converter as x:Arguments for `controls:IngredientsSearchHandler`. That's how you initialize a control with parameterized constructor

Comment: @shanranm you do not need to use x:Arguments when using the ContainerProvider as it is using the DI Container to Resolve the type. You only need to specify the TypeArguments since it is a generic type `ContainerProvider<T>` It will return the type `T` automatically.